# Vk Direct Link Vidoes on Android

Tags: android, video-streaming, vk

I have a button in my android app. When I press it, Android video player will open and make vk video link play! 
e.g. for link:
http://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=3145131&id=159485516&hash=d821df23b7dc0b54&hd=1

I use this code but this opens in browser.

```
   Uri address = Uri.parse("http://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=3145131&id=159485516&hash=d821df23b7dc0b54&hd=1");
   Intent openlink = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, address);
   activity.startActivity(openlink);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add "Type" of intent, in this case it is "video/*". Here is the solution:

```
 Intent openlink = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 openlink.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("url"), "video/*");            
 startActivity(Intent.createChooser(openlink, "Complete action using"));
```